# Convert a linux command to python command

Tags: python, linux, shell, terminal, adb

Would you please say me how can I convert this code:

```
path to app/adb devices | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % install app.apk
```

to python command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a program or call a system command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python)

Comment: Not really ....

Comment: The second answer in the link I suggested is precisely the same as the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always utilize the [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) method:

```
import os

command = "path to app/adb devices | awk 'NR>1{print $1}' | xargs -n1 -I% adb -s % install app.apk"

os.system(command)
```